# Rails: What determines name of "params" passed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I can't quite find the answer on the internet for this seemingly simple problem.

What I've gone through tutorial apps, for say a basic CRUD app...and lets say your normal User create/edit/update/delete pages.

Typically you see something like:

`params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)`

So this means the params passed is `params(:user)` right?

However sometimes, such as when doing a `link_to` and passing something to to a POST request (Such as a patch or update or something similar) the param is simply `params[:id]`. What determines what the `params(:<name>)` is going to be called?

It seems to be dependent on forms...but sometimes not? Does it just default to `id` otherwise or something?

Comment: What, exactly, is the "seemingly simple problem" here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be determined by the route, by the input tag or by you.

By the route:

```rb
rails routes -g user 
   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern               Controller#Action
   signup GET    /signup(.:format)         users#new
    users GET    /users(.:format)          users#index
          POST   /users(.:format)          users#create
edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) users#edit
     user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      users#show
          PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
          PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
          DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      users#destroy
```

Here, `params[:id]` is set by the url helper like `edit_user_path(@user)`. You can set your own param name in `config/routes.rb`:

```rb
get 'profile/:user_id', to: 'users#show'
```

```rb
rails routes -g profile 
Prefix Verb URI Pattern                 Controller#Action
       GET  /profile/:user_id(.:format) users#show
```

By the input:

```rb
<%= form_for @user... do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name
<% end %>
```

Here, the form sets `params: {user: {name: some_value}}`, because the model object used by the form is `User` and the column name is `name`.

And by you:

```rb
link_to 'Profile', user_path(@user, locale: 'en')
```

which outputs: `<a href=\"/users/1?locale=en\">Profile</a>`

Answer (score 1):

Rails guide [mentions this](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters)

`params` is combination of:

1. routing parameters
2. GET-parameters (`example.org/page?some_param=value`)
3. POST parameters (form data, decoded json, etc.)

`params[:id]` usually comes from routing parameters (`/users/:id`), there can be other route params (for example other common case is nested routes like `/users/:user_id/some_other_resources/:id` - there will be `:user_id` and `:id`)
and by convention saved object is passed in `params[:model_name]`

Answer (score 1):

Parameters are part of HTTP requests. HTTP requests have no restrictions on what can be sent as a parameter (outside of size of data being sent). So, you can send a request to any route on your server with params.

Rails attempts to prevent any evil, sneaky, people from injecting parameters and values where they don't belong. We can do that by creating a method that wraps our params object in a specified structure:

```
params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
```

This means `params` must be sent in this format:

```
user: {
  name: "name",
  password: "password",
  password_confirmation: "password"
}
```

If you check your logs in development, Rails will display your params (should any be sent) in each request. If your params are not in that format (with a user at the root level) and you use the method `user_params`, it will throw an error. `user` is *required*. And should someone send the parameters:

```
user: {
  name: "name",
  pseudonym: "sneaky param",
  password: "password",
  password_confirmation: "password"
}
```

Rails will still accept `name`, `password`, and `password_confirmation`, but it will reject `pseudonym` because it is not permitted by your method `user_params`.

You'll see in a lot of code, people grab the `params[:id]` value directly. That's because we're often only using that to read or destroy an item. `*_params` methods are usually reserved for CREATE and UPDATE actions in the controller because that's where we are injecting params.

It's not technically necessary. Rails is already sanitizing user input in the Active Record queries. So, it's not a direct requirement for a secure app. You could pull the params directly from the params hash, rather than using this method. But it certainly keeps your code DRY. It also ensures you're not giving user's access to important metadata in your model. For example, if you're SO, you might (though unlikely) have an upvote column for my post. If you whitelist all params and just accept all params into the `Post.update(params)` method, I could send a `POST` request with the params `upvotes: 1,000,000`. I don't think they'd like that at all.